# Can't turn transitions off

Tags: android, transition

I'm trying to have no animation between some of my transitions. I have this bit bit of code:

```
    TextView pulse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pulseText);
    pulse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Pulse.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

So to stop animation, I added this after starting the activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

But that caused an error saying, "The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}".
So then I tried adding

```
`myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ACTION);`
```

before starting the activity, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried Activity.overridePendingTransition(0,0); and that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try writing:

```
ActivityClassName.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

where `ActivityClassName` is the name of your activity class

**EDIT:**

To start Board.class from Pulse.class, instead of writing:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Pulse.class);
```

It should be:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Board.class);
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still got a message saying overridePendingTransition(0, 0); is undefined for type Pulse (my class name)

Comment: Sorry for asking a really obvious question, but is Pulse a subclass of Activity?

Comment: Yes, it is a subclass of Activity.

Comment: Are you doing starting activity Pulse from activity Pulse?

Comment: I'm trying to start activity Board from Pulse. When you wrote ActivityClassName did you mean the class I'm transitioning to?

Comment: No, but in this line: Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Pulse.class);
You pass Pulse.class. If you are starting board, it should be: Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Board.class);

Comment: oh wow, I can't believe I just did that. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer to make it clearer for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 1):

You must go to your `class Pulse`

Add to onCreate(Bundle) the line:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

and probably you want to add this line to the `onCreate()` of all your activities