# Android - overridePendingTransaction(0,0) flashes screen on API level 26 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using **overridePendingTransaction(0,0)** to void the animations. All of a sudden, I can see this code piece is causing flickering on Oreo.

All I'm doing is, in some of the base classes

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

If I comment this line, I can get rid of the issue. I have seen some similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401883/oreo-disable-activity-transition-animation)

Any help to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this can help but found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950215/4219444

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on Oreo. The solution in the following worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401883/oreo-disable-activity-transition-animation

Comment: @hustoj2 Thanks. I am using this atm. Thought if any other solutions are accurate